# Controlling formatting options for xtable

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

All,

I'm a LaTex/knitr/Sweave amateur and have had trouble finding answers to what seem like they should be fairly simple questions online. I have a .Rnw script that I am currently compiling to PDF using `knitr`'s `knit2pdf` function. Within that script I have tables converted to LaTex format using `xtable`. I would like to do two things:

(1) Lose the "Table 1:" label. Apparently this is not as straightforward as passing a blank or NA character string to `xtable`'s `label` argument.

(2) Increase the font size of the table entries

Here is a simple .Rnw script. I've saved this as `'test_template.Rnw'`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%Save this script file as 'test_template.Rnw' in an easy-to-access location. 

\begin{document}

<<test_table, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
MAT <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
print(xtable(MAT, caption = '\\textbf{Test Table}', label = ''), 
      caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"))
@

\end{document}
```

and here is the R code that I am using to render the PDF:

```
install.packages('knitr')
library(knitr)
setwd('SET WORKING DIRECTORY HERE') #..Note: Working directory should match the location of the .Rnw file. 
knit2pdf('test_template.Rnw')
```

**UPDATE**

Scott's answer was right on target. Note that that label formatting options have to be coded independently within the label character string using double escapes ('\\'). Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}

<<test_table, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
MAT <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
print(xtable(MAT, caption = '\\textbf{\\Huge{Test Table}}', label = ''), 
  caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"), size = 'Huge')
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting rid of the prefix, you can use the caption package and then

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
```

For increasing the font size, note in `?print.xtable`

```
size: An arbitrary character vector intended to be used to set the
      font size in a LaTeX table.  The supplied value (if not
      ‘NULL’) is inserted just before the tabular environment
      starts.  Default value is ‘NULL’.
```

I'm not sure what syntax it's looking for.

Alternatively you could probably increase the font size as you would normally for text in LaTeX before the table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to play around with it for a little bit, but these were the right solutions answers. I've added my revised script which answers both questions.